# Not able to switch to popup window in pycahrm

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

```
    def switch_to_popup(self):
    my_popup = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="a-popover-1"]')
    self.driver.switch_to(my_popup)
```

Using the above function to switch to popup in the following url -> https://www.amazon.in/
but getting the following error -> TypeError: 'SwitchTo' object is not callable

Click on the following to get the popup manually -> https://prnt.sc/26bpmr0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if switch_to is needed. The below allows you to click on the "Select your address" button and then input some postcode:

```
def switch_to_popup():
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.nav-a.nav-a-2.a-popover-trigger.a-declarative.nav-progressive-attribute').click()
time.sleep(2)
# Type a postcode
driver.find_element_by_id("GLUXZipUpdateInput").send_keys("Hello_")
```